# ¿Como tomar la primera letra dentro de un String en Javascript si el primer caracter es un numero?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Por ejemplo

> 12kghggdhfj74ghg8hgh

De la cadena debo tomar el `12` y la `k` pero el texto puede cambiar puede ser

> 127rnbvcx

Y de ahi debo de tomar el `127` y la `r` y guardarla en cada variable

**PD. las cadenas son ingresadas desde un input**

Comment: Ademas de numeros y letras pueden haber otros caracteres, como puntos, comas, caracteres espciales?

Comment: Quiero que omita los caracteres especiales, solamente me interesa la primera letra dentro de un string y los primeros números

Comment: Que resultado esperas de los siguientes inputs?: "#@1k" , "#123??1k"

Comment: 1k , 1231k aunque la idea es que el usuario solo ingrese numeros y letras, la aplicacion que estoy haciendo es para que multiplique variables tipo algebraico

Comment: La respuesta que buscas debe asumir que pueden haber caracteres especiales o que previamente ya se limito el input a letras y numeros? Es importante dejar claro eso.

Comment: No necesariamente, eso seria como algo extra en cuanto a validaciones, si lo tome en cuenta pero por el momento no me enfoco en eso, creo que eso lo dejare al final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una posible solución que contempla la omisión de caracteres especiales, asumo que, como se menciona en el título de la pregunta, los primeros caracteres son números

El algoritmo consiste en iterar sobre la cadena de números y letras, acumulando dígitos hasta encontrar la primera letra, retornando un objeto. Para chequear por si un valor es numérico me he basado en lo discutido en la siguiente pregunta: [how to check whether a value is a number in javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449611/how-to-check-whether-a-value-is-a-number-in-javascript-or-jquery)

```js
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function processInput(input){
   let result = {
     firstNumber:"",
     firstLetter:""
   }
   const cleanInput = input.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''); // reemplazo todo lo que no sea una letra o un digito. Esto podria no ser necesario si ya se asume que se controla en el ingreso de datos.
   console.log("input: %s, clean input: %s", input, cleanInput);
   for (let i in cleanInput) {
     if(isNumeric(cleanInput[i])){
        result.firstNumber += cleanInput[i];
     }else{
        result.firstLetter = cleanInput[i];
        break;
     }
  } 
  return result;
}


console.log(processInput("123dkkkk"));
console.log(processInput("23dk"));
console.log(processInput("1d23dkkkk"));
console.log(processInput("#11d23dk"));
console.log(processInput("#1..1??#23dk"));
console.log(processInput("#1..1??#DDD23dk"));
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo , de momento me tengo que retirar pero te lo agradezco por la ayuda, efectivamente los resultados que salen en la ejecución de tu código son los que buscaba

Answer (score 0):

Otra posible solución sería la siguiente; seguramente se puede hacer todo con una expresión regular más compleja (si algún crack en regexp la sabe siéntase libre de sugerirla).

```js
const getSerie = (str) => {
  if(isNaN(str[0])) { throw new Error('Serie must start with a number'); }
  const matches = str.match(/\d+\.\d+|\d+\b|\d+(?=\w)/);
  const match = matches[0];
  const index = matches.indexOf(match) + match.length;
  const nextChar = str.substr(index, 1);
  const isLetter = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(nextChar);

  if (isLetter) {
    return match + nextChar;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

// Ejemplo
const serie1 = getSerie("12rdjdjdf4kgjdg");
const serie2 = getSerie("123fdjdjdf4kgjdg");
const serie3 = getSerie("123$djdjdf4kgjdg");

console.log('Serie:', serie1);
console.log('Serie:', serie2);
console.log('Serie:', serie3);

const serie4 = getSerie("adjdjd5f4kgjdg"); // error

console.log('Serie:', serie4);
```